# How to send the data from the script to HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, console.log

I am using Firebase to get the data

code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("C:/Users/santo/Downloads/bestmpos-firebase-adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

let fs = admin.firestore();
let auth = admin.auth();

const listAllUsers = async (nextPageToken) => {
  try {
    let result = await auth.listUsers(100, nextPageToken);
    result.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
      start(userRecord.toJSON())
    });
    if (result.pageToken) {
      listAllUsers(result.pageToken);
    }
  } catch(ex) {
      console.log('Exception listing users:', ex.message);
  }
}

async function first(){
    await listAllUsers();
}
first();

async function start (object){
  const info = await fs.collection('users').doc(object.uid).get();
  if (!info.exists) {
    console.log('No document');
   } else {
    console.table([info.data()]);
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = info.data().toString();

   }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="greeting"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

but I want to send data `console.log(info.data())` to HTML page to simply show information,

How can I do that, I don't want to use react or any other
can someone help me?
and I also is this Nodejs or plain javascript?

Comment: You can use [HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) , [HTMLElement..textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) , [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHTML` to sent data in your html.

Like this:

```
document.getElementById("yourElementId").innerHTML = info.data();
```

This is working for me:

```
<p id="greeting">

</p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "test"
</script>
```

Comment: It is showing error saying **    document.getElementById("yourElementId").innerHTML = info.data();
  
ReferenceError: document is not defined**

Comment: Yes because in the double citations you should write your html element id

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="app3.js"></script>` `<p id="greeting"></p>`. `    `document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = info.data();`
`I have written html element ID but it is not working.

Comment: I've changed my code, try it again

Comment: It is not about converting to sting, it is saying **document** is not defined

Comment: can you share your html code as well?

Comment: I've edited my code. I've tried the code that I wrote and it works.

Comment: I have changed my code and added html code... by the way  the code I have shared is plain javascript only right?

Comment: Yes but I think it doesnt matter. it should work, cause every thing is correct !

can you just copy and paste your code in the `<script></script>` tags below your html and test it?

Comment: Tried, not working like that also, nothing is printing